# Play Framework [2.4.x] Twitter example. Curious as to this particular construct for a generator

Tags: scala, dictionary, playframework-2.0

Working with example from this page:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaOAuth

and suddenly this sort of popped out at me:

```
  def sessionTokenPair(implicit request: RequestHeader): Option[RequestToken] = {
    for {
      token <- request.session.get("token")
      secret <- request.session.get("secret")
    } yield {
      RequestToken(token, secret)
    }
  }
```

As I understood a generator (for comprehension) the second entry was based on the results of the first generator.

e.g.: `secret <- request.session.get("secret")` would have come from something out of `token <- request.session.get("token")`

Yet clearly when you look at what the outcome is `RequestToken(token, secret)` that would not be the case.

How/why is this construct superior to simply doing:

```
RequestToken(request.session.get("token"), request.session.get("secret"))
```

Ah - I think i might be answering this myself as I ask the question (but it still doesn't explain the "equalness?" of the two lines versus one line leading to the next...)

The output of this is an `Option` as it comes from a mapping process whereas if we jumped directly in the constructor we have no way to deal with a `None` situation.

So can anyone clarify why this works if `secret` is NOT related to the generator for `token`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scala for-comprehension is syntactic sugar for `flatMap`. If you used `flatMap` instead, this is what the above expression would look like:

```
request.session.get("token").flatMap { token =>
  request.session.get("secret").flatMap { secret =>
    Some(RequestToken(token, secret))
  }
}
```

-which yields an `Option[RequestToken]`.

The point of this method is to yield a `RequestToken` only if both `secret` and `token` are defined. If **either is not** defined, it results in `None`.

To answer your question, the second expression in the for comprehension was based on the results of the first expression only to the extent that if the first expression yields `None`, the second expression is not invoked - just like the inner `flatMap` is not invoked if getting the `token` yielded `None`.

Finally, I'd like to correct some of the terms you've used. A for-comprehension is not a generator. Generators can be used with for-comprehensions, but that's because they're monads which have `flatMap` and `filter` defined. Incidentally, any monad which has `flatMap` and `filter` defined (e.g. `Option`, `Future`, `List`, etc.) can be used with a for-comprehension.

I like to think of the `<-` operator as *"let me take the value out of that wrapper (monad) for a second"*. So inside a for comprehension, the following holds:

```
token = request.session.get("token") // this is an Option[Token]
token <- request.session.get("token") // this is a Token - we've taken it out of its wrapper
```

Comment: Thank you or the examples -- that "taking the token out of it's wrapper might be uber handy for any things. I always saw that as a iterator (when used in @twirl templates for example) but just maybe this is an `iterator of one` perhaps? (But then how would you distinguish between an iteratable and just a wrapper (or for that matter a collection of wrapped items). Sometimes we like sugar too much? :)

Comment: @Techmag in cases where the monad wraps multiple elements, the LHS still represents one element, but the subsequent expressions, including the `yield`, will be invoked for **each** of the elements.

Comment: @Techmag as for a collection of wrapped items, the LHS would represent a single wrapped item at a time. e.g. `<-` on a `List[Option[Int]]` would give you an `Option[Int]` for each element.

Answer (score 1):

If one of the productions (which return an `Option`)

```
token <- request.session.get("token")
secret <- request.session.get("secret")
```

returns `None`, the result of the for comprehension will be `None` as well (there could be more than just two productions).

In other words, only if all of these return `Some`thing, the result will be an instance of `Some`.

In case of `Option`s it's like iterating over the content of a list which has zero or one elements.

The type of the first production in a for comprehension will determine the type of the overall result, in this case `Option` and this matches the return type of the method `sessionTokenPair`.

The difference to a simple `RequestToken(...)` is that the value is wrapped in an `Option`. This clearly differs between "no value" and "there is a value". You otherwise need something like an `isEmpty` method in `RequestToken`, but this is generalized by using an `Option` (and this is the preferred way in Scala).

Then the caller can "pattern match" on the result. And the compiler will enforce it that you somehow handle the `Option`.